# Cross-domain AJAX calls in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, google-chrome

Firefox and Internet Explorer both have settings where a user may enable forbidden cross-domain calls.

Is there a similar setting or option in Safari and/or Chrome?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure about safari, but Chrome has a command line switch for this:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

You can view a full list (as of when it was posted!) of [command line options for chrome here](http://yuridejager.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/chromium-chrome-command-line-switches/).

Comment: This is one of my biggest complaints about the webkit browsers - the 'all or nothing' security preferences.  Is it that hard to write 'disable-web-security-for-trusted-domains'?

Comment: if you need authentication you would also need to use this parameter:
--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt
otherwise it will fail as if web security is still enabled