# javascript problem to get meebo sessionId

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-chrome

I'm trying to write a plugin to use Meebo in Google Chrome, but the problem is that XMLHttpRequests from other servers than www.meebo.com are not allowed. If I type "https://www.meebo.com/mcmd/start.cgi?type=mobile&allowIPChange=true" into addressbar there is no problem and I get back the JSON data, but I want to use it in my script, so is there any solution to get the data returned from the meebo servers and use it in my script?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without using a server unless meebo has implemented [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP)

Alternatively turn off (bad idea) web security in Chrome: [Cross-domain AJAX calls in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675298/ajax-cross-domain-in-safari-chrome)