# Chrome force-allow cross-domain AJAX jQuery requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome (v24) and want to use jQuery to access a remote data source from my development env (say, from a 'localhost' client). How can I force Chrome (or all browsers) to allow cross-domain requests?

For example, how can I force Chrome to allow the following standard AJAX call to succeed:

```
$.get('http://google.com',function(res){console.log(res);})
```

Comment: Don't know if this is going to help but, did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675298/ajax-cross-domain-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score -1):

JSONP.  Also have a RESTful web service on the other end of course.